# Passing value from ModelAdmin to ModelForm

Tags: django

InstrumentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin)

```
def get_form(self,request, obj=None, **kwargs):
    if obj:
        return UpdateForm
    else:
        return CreateForm
```

1. How can i pass a value (obj.id) to UpdateForm in this case? I need the value to grab data from another table in Database and display it in a custom field of UpdateForm.
2. How I can get the value from ModelForm?

I have look for a lot of example but still can't figure it out how it works. Appriciate for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You have some problems in your code. The method `get_form()` is explicitly meant to return the form that you want to use, but right now you are returning the super class form and the first check is pretty much useless. So that should probably be sth like this:

```
def get_form(self,request, obj=None, **kwargs):
    if obj:
        return UpdateForm
    else:
        return CreateForm
```

1. How to pass values to form? Just add the value as a keyword argument, for example, if your form field name is `value`, do it like `return CreateForm(value=10)`.

As for second question, could you elaborate what value do you want to get from which ModelForm?

Comment: I would like to pass an integer for example 10 to the UpdateForm. I need the value to grab some data from Database.

Comment: For more information, I would like to pass obj.id to the form.

Comment: Do you mean when you're using the UpdateForm? Do you mean you want to prefill the form with existing data?